# Play Framework: How to Validate Optional Fields When Parsing JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
     "nickname": "mj",
     "firstname": "Mike",
     "lastName": "Jordan",
     "trash": "ignore"
}
```

... I need to parse and validate it so that

1. any field except `nickname`, `firstName`, and `lastName` are filtered out – in my example above `trash` has to be removed
2. if defined, `nickname` (which is optional) must be at least 3 characters long

Here below is my code:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

def orEmpty = reads | __.json.put(Json.obj())    

val js = Json.parse("""{ "nickname": "mj", "firstname": "Mike", "lastName": "Jordan" }""")

val validateUser = (
  ((__ \ 'nickname).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString] <~ Reads.minLength[String](3)) orEmpty) ~
  ((__ \ 'firstName).json.pickBranch) ~
  ((__ \ 'lastName).json.pickBranch)
)

validateUser.reads(js).fold(
  valid = { validated => JsSuccess(js) },
  invalid => { errors => JsError(errors) }
)
```

The problem is that if `nickname` is invalid because shorter than 3 characters, `orEmpty` applies and no error is reported. What I need is to keep `nickname` optional (that's why I defined `orEmpty`), but when defined the validation should succeed if and only if `nickanme` passes the `Reads.minLength` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Play Framework 2.4.x. I believe reading nullable fields is a little different in 2.3.x but it's the same idea.

It would be easier to reason about this if you assume that JSON validators and transformers are really just `Reads[T <: JsValue]`.

Overall, what you need to consider is that the `nickname` field is actually optional and you need to represent it as such. Basically, what you're looking for is to compose the `nullableReads` with `Reads.minLength` to read nickname as `Option[String]`.

So, you can represent the structure you want to validate as:

```
case class ToValidate(nickname: Option[String], firstname: String, lastname: String)
```

And define you're Reader:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val toValidateReads: Reads[ToValidate] = (
  (__ \ "nickname").readNullable[String](minLength(3)) ~
  (__ \ "firstname").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "lastname").read[String]
)(ToValidate.apply _)
```

Then you can vaildate your input:

```
val js = Json.parse("""{ "nickname": "mj", "firstname": "Mike", "lastname": "Jordan" }""")
val v = js.validate[ToValidate]
println(v) // JsError(List((/nickname,List(ValidationError(List(error.minLength),WrappedArray(3))))))
```